# How do I find records that don't have an association with given conditions? (ActiveRecord / PostgreSQL)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I have the following ActiveRecord models:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :user_alert_archives
end

class UserAlertArchive < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :alert
end

class Alert < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :user_alert_archives
end
```

When a user archives a given alert, a UserAlertArchive record gets created with that user's id and the alert id. Running a query for the user's archived alerts is fairly trivial.

```
Alert.joins(:user_alert_archives).where(user_alert_archives: {user_id: current_user.id})
```

It's querying for the inverse of that scenario that I'm having trouble wrapping my head around. How would I do an efficient query for alert records that *don't* have a UserAlertArchive with the current user's id associated?

--edit--

This is a little difficult to explain but this is the only way I've been able to get the desired results:

```
archived_ids = Alert.joins(:user_alert_archives).where(user_alert_archives: {user_id: current_user.id}).pluck(:id)
Alert.where.not(id: archived_ids)
```

This technically works but it pulls all the ids of archived alerts which is pretty slow for users with thousands of them. I'd like to be able to accomplish it in a single query if possible.

Comment: I don' think you need to join to get what you want. And if you combine the calls it will only run one query.

    Alert.where.not(id: current_user.user_alert_archives.select(:id))

Comment: Well, now I feel ridiculous. That is indeed a pointless join. Finding the alerts is a little more complex in our production code and I had a brain fart while stripping it down to post here. But thanks for pointing out that ActiveRecord will combine that into a sub query automatically. I didn't realize that it was smart enough to do a "NOT IN" on its own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Rails 5 (where method 'jeft_joins' exits)

```
Alert.left_joins(:user_alert_archives).where(user_alert_archives: {id: nil})
```

That will display all alerts which have never been archived by anyone.

If you want all alerts, which haven't been archived by some specific user, then maybe you will need to add some sql:

```
Alert.where('id NOT IN (SELECT alert_id FROM user_alerts_archives u WHERE u.customer_id = ?)', current_user.id)
```

If you had a model like UserAlert, which was holding an alert status (like 'pending', 'archived'), then querying them could be more beautiful and smooth.

Answer (score 0):

I like [M. Stavnycha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7251206/m-stavnycha)'s approach of using a sub-select so you don't have to pass a large number of `id`s to an `IN` clause. I would recommend putting that in a scope or class method on `Alert`. i.e.

```
class Alert < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :alert_archives

  def self.unviewed(user_id)
    where("id NOT IN (SELECT alert_id FROM user_alert_archives WHERE user_id = ?)", user_id)
  end
end
```